Does a event with probability of 1 cover all outcomes in a sample space?
In probability theory, if probabilities of all outcomes add up to 1, does an event with probability of 1 cover all the outcomes?
In the microorganism problem, there is a very large petri dish starts with a single microorganism. "After one minute, the microorganism either splits into two with probability $s$, or dies. All subsequent microorganisms behave in the same way — splitting into two or dying after each minute — independently of each other."
The probability of event extinction conditioned on the first one dies is 1. If the sample space is like 00000000, 10101010101, 00000001 and so on where 0 means the cell dies and 1 means the cell splits, does the extinction event with probability of 1 covers all these outcomes?
Thanks,

The answer is no. This is well-known in the theory of probability, an event with probability 1 doesn't mean that all scenarios belong to that event.

Could I have a quick reference for this please? I was trying google search but couldn't find one.

I think what you need is a first course in modern probability theory. Maybe a good book is "Probability and Random Processes" by Grimmett or "Measure theory" - Le Gall

Thanks @JeffreyJao

A good example is the following: Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, meaning that the probability that $X$ lands in some interval $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$ is exactly $b-a$. Then the probability that $X$ takes on a rational value, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(X\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})$, equals zero, however the are an infinite (yet countable) number of rational points between zero and one. The reason for this has to do with the so-called countable additivity of measures. In this case, the probability of an event $A$ is simply the Lebesgue measure of $A$. A good reference is thus an intro in measures.

It's a very good example indeed, thanks @Daan.
If we look at the example in my post, the number of possible outcomes is vast (infinite), the favourable outcomes are however those with 0s, 00000000, 000000, 00000, 0, which is also infinite, so that might explain why it can still be assigned 1 for the event's probability.

If i understand you correctly, defining your event space in this way does not make sense. See suppose after the first period, the first (and only) organism splits, then we have two organisms who now have four different possible outcomes, either they both die, both split or a combination of splitting and dying. Do i understand your situation correctly?

Yes, you understand that correctly. However if you define a different sample space, we will be in a different probability space and then that in theory wouldn't make sense to compare the variables at different time step. For example in book [https://bookdown.org/kevin_davisross/probsim-book/independence2.html], the author suggests that there is a conditioned probability on the first microorganism, so that means events from time steps were coming from the same probability space.

A similar situation I think is the sample space of experiment where you flip the coin until a head comes up. The sample space is infinite.

In your case, we have a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ indexed by the nonnegative integers, where each canonical representation $t\mapsto X_t$ is defined to be the (random) number of microorganisms at time $t$ where $X_0=1$. Hence each so-called path $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)$ indeed takes its values in an infinite dimensional space, namely $\mathbb{N}_0^{\mathbb{N}_0}$, as you mentioned earlier.
Now if one is interested in the probability that the sample of organisms dies out given a certain value of $s\in[0,1]$, then it is not convenient to look at the process in this infinite-dimensional space, but rather at the probability
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_t=0\:\text{for some }t>0)
\end{equation}
since $X_t(\omega)=0$ implies that $X_s(\omega)=0$ for every $s\geq t$ (each organism died so no new organisms can spawn). As luck would have it, this is a well-known problem in stochastic analysis called the branching process. Mathematically speaking, we again define $X_t$ as the number of living organisms at time $t$ and for each $i=1,...,X_t$, we define $Z_{t+1,i}$ as independent random variables taking value 2 with probability $s$ and value 0 with probability $1-s$ such that
\begin{equation}
X_{t+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{X_t}Z_{t+1,i}\quad\forall t\geq 0
\end{equation}
with the convention that $\sum_{i=1}^0Z_{t,i}=0$. Now we can reformulate the question "given $s$, what is the probability that the sample dies out" as
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_t=0).
\end{equation}
Now if $s<1/2$, then the expected number of offspring of each individual is less than one, that is, $\mathbb{E}(Z_{t,i})<1$, which also means that the ultimate extinction probability is one. Note here that, although $\mathbb{P}(X_t=0\:\text{for some }t>0)=1$, we can simply take $\omega$ such that $X_t(\omega)=1$ if $t=0$ and $X_t(\omega)=2$ for $t\geq 1$ (of course this can not be done like that as we do not know if such an $\omega$ exists, but for our sake, we will do so). In case that $s\geq 1/2$, the math becomes more intricate, but it will be a nice exercise to see how to relate $s$ to the extinction probability in this case.
As a hint, try to google the Galton-Watson process. I hope this helps and please correct me if anything is wrong.

I will need to level up my math to further comment on your post. In the meantime, I'm simulating this with s = 0.75, the result looks like it's agreeing with the theoretical answer of 1/3:

https://gitlab.com/soncaodo/any_codes/-/blob/main/extinction.py?ref_type=heads

I am not sure your code works. Try to make a separate function that takes as input the population size at time $t$ and the decision rule, in your case the parameter $s$, and returns the new population size for time $t+1$. Then you can run this function recursively until either it returns zero, or the maximal recursion depth is reached (10.000 will do in this scenario). This is also more readable.

Yes, indeed. I think you framed the problem really elegantly which allows the simulations to go much further.  My code has a limit of $2^n$ size, where $n$ is the number of generations. Your way can go way higher (10000 like you said). The book reference I gave gave solution for $p$, probability of going extinction in terms of $s$ as solutions of:
$p = (1)(1-s) + (p^2)s$
